# Reading a line uptil certain character in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am reading such type of lines from a file. I want to extract this number 12 (or any other number) before forward slash

12/1000 class states (till end)

Right now my code just extracts the above whole line from a file but I need the number before forwardslash. How can I do that

```
if (strstr (line,"class states")!=NULL) {
    if (file3!= NULL ) {
        fprintf(file3, "%s", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just grab the whole line and then look for the 12 once it's read in?

Comment: This number will be different each time.

Comment: why not read the whole line and then look for the number before the slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of functions you might use to parse out the particular part of the line you're looking for: any of `sscanf`, `strchr` (or `index`), and `strtok` might be appropriate, depending on what you're looking for. (For example, is the separator always a single '/', or do you need to handle multi-character separators).

In all cases, as xaxxon suggests, you'll want to first read in the whole line using something like `fgets`, then call your function of choice to split it up.

----edit----
If you know that your number is always before the first '/', you could do something like:

```
int number;
if (sscanf(line, "%d/", &number) == 1) {
       printf("number found = %d\n", number);
} else {
       printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
}
```

The "%d/" is a pattern that tells sscanf to match a decimal number, followed by a '/'. sscanf returns the number of input values assigned, so if it's not "1", the input line was not in the expected format.

Comment: The separator will always be a '/'

Answer (score 1):

Use `strchr` to find the separator character and read till that.

Answer (score 1):

The way is quite simple ... you almost have it:

Let's look a more complete picture:

```
int main() {

    char line[256]; /* a long enough line */
    char *p;
    FILE *fin, *fout;

    fin = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
    fout = stderr; /* you can change this to another open file later */

    while(!feof(fin)) {

         fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin);
         p = strstr(line, "class states"); 

         if ( p ) { /* we found the line */
              /* okay here p is a pointer that points to 
               * the beginning of the phrase class states but we want just 
                 12 (or whatever) before the  /1000 so we use strchr this time */
              p = strchr(line, '/'); /* now we are at the first slash */
              *p = 0; /* change the slash(/) to NUL and that 
                       * makes the line end at number 12 */
              fprintf(fout, "%s\n", line); 
         }   
    }
}
```

Here is a slightly cleaner way with a bit of error checking. Note that I reversed the if (p) logic to avoid large blocks of tabbed code.

```
int main() {

    char line[256]; /* a long enough line */
    char *p;
    FILE *fin, *fout;

    fin = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");

    if ( !fin ) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open `somefile.txt' for reading\n");
       return -1;
    }

    fout = fopen("savedfile.txt", "w");

    if ( !fout ) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open `savedfile.txt' for writing\n");
       return -1;
    }


    while(!feof(fin)) {

         fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin);
         p = strstr(line, "class states"); 

         if ( !p ) { /* we did not find the line */
              continue;
         }
         /* everything below this happens when we find the line */

         /* okay when we get here p is a pointer that points to 
          * the beginning of the phrase class states but we want just 
            12 (or whatever) before the  /1000 so we use strchr this time */

          p = strchr(line, '/'); /* now we are at the first slash */

          if ( !p ) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Didn't find a slash in `%s'\n", line);
             continue; /* go on to the next line */
          }

          *p = 0; /* change the slash(/) to NUL and that 
                   * makes the line end at number 12 */
         fprintf(fout, "%s\n", line); 

    }

    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```